# Tensorflow 2: variable and ops placement on different devices (GPU/CPU) using tf.device and MirroredStrategy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, distributed-computing, tensorflow2.0

I would like to store different variables and run different tensorflow ops on different devices (GPU/CPU). I want to do this because my model cannot fit on a single GPU. I am trying to train embeddings. I want to place recurring words on all GPUs and non common words on different devices (as a part of preprocessing I do all this) and transfer sentences to respective GPUs.

For the this question I am not pasting my actual code. I am writing a snippet which is close to what I want to do. When I run the code, I do not get any error and neither does it execute successfully. I think the problem is that this code gets stuck (may be deadlock on GPU).

Below is the snippet. For the sake of simplicity say I want to do  `y = x * w1 + x * w2 + 2 * w3`, where `w1`, `w2` and `w3` are trainable variables. I place `w1` on `GPU0` and `w2` on `GPU1`. Instead of doing the `2 * w3` on a single device say I want to split it and perform on 2 devices (to see how mirrored strategy works). I perform respective computations on respective GPUs. First of all is that a correct way to do it (using mirrored scope to assign devices to variables). Secondly if it is wrong why does tensorflow not throw any error, why is it getting stuck and why is it showing 100% GPU usage?

If i change all the device/scopes to a single GPU it executes successfully but I don't want that. I want to place some variables on single devices and some on both and perform computations as I illustrated below to speed up processing.

```
import os

#os.environ['TF2_BEHAVIOR'] = '1'
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()

#tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

tf.config.set_soft_device_placement(False)
tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)
import numpy as np

class ProdLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(ProdLayer, self).__init__()
        self.w = tf.keras.backend.variable(0.01, name='var_'+ name)


    def call(self, x):
        return x * self.w 

class SumLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SumLayer, self).__init__()

    def call(self, x1, x2):
        return x1 + x2


mirrored_strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(devices=["/gpu:0", "/gpu:1"])

class EmbeddingModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(EmbeddingModel, self).__init__()

        # place w1 on GPU 0 and create the layer
        with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
            self.L1 = ProdLayer('w1')

        # place w2 on GPU 0 and create the layer        
        with tf.device('/gpu:1'):
            self.L2 = ProdLayer('w2')

        # place w3 on both GPU0 and GPU1 using mirrored scope. Can I do this?
        with mirrored_strategy.scope():
            self.w3 = tf.keras.backend.variable(0.01, name='var_w3')

        # may be do this on CPU? But for now let it perform this on GPU0
        with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
            self.L3 = SumLayer()


    def call(self, input_layer):
        # w1 is on GPU0, w2 is on GPU1 and w3 is placed using mirrored scope on both GPUs
        # y1 = w1 * x + w3
        with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
            y1 = self.L1(input_layer) + self.w3

        # y2 = w2 * x + w3
        with tf.device('/gpu:1'):
            y2 = self.L2(input_layer) + self.w3

        # y = y1 + y2 (i.e. w1 * x + w2 * x + 2 * w3) 
        with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
            y_hat = self.L3(y1, y2)

        return y_hat


def myLoss(y, y_hat):
    return (y_hat-y) * (y_hat-y)

with mirrored_strategy.scope():
    model = EmbeddingModel()
    model.compile(tf.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001), 
                      loss=myLoss)

train_dataset = np.random.choice(100, size=(1000,))
model.fit(x=train_dataset.astype(np.float32), y=train_dataset.astype(np.float32), 
       batch_size=1000, 
       epochs=10, shuffle=False, verbose=True)
```